# Dependencies in Makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose I have a Makefile:

```
all: $(BINARY)

$(BINARY): $(OBJS) $(DEBUG_OBJS)
    #Link objects here

$(OBJS): headers
    #Compile code into objects without debug option

$(DEBUG_OBJS): headers
    #Compile code into objects with debug option

headers:
    #Create on-the-fly header files
```

As you can see, the target `headers` is required by both `$(OBJS)` and `$(DEBUG_OBJS)`. The question is, will `headers` be called twice? Also, would the below code be equal/equivalent to the above:

```
all: $(BINARY)

$(BINARY): headers $(OBJS) $(DEBUG_OBJS)
    #Link objects here

$(OBJS): 
    #Compile code into objects without debug option

$(DEBUG_OBJS): 
    #Compile code into objects with debug option

headers:
    #Create on-the-fly header files
```

in that, would headers get called before `$(OBJS)` and `$(DEBUG_OBJS)` by `$(BINARY)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `headers` will be done just once.

You can write a simple makefile to test it:

```
all: foo bar

foo: baz

bar: baz

baz:
        echo 'hi'
```

On doing `make`, `hi` will be echoed just once.

And in your 2nd case make sees that `$(BINARY)` depends on `headers` first, so it goes and does `headers` before other dependencies.